# Filtering out SQL result when all rows match a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given some very complex and expensive SQL query result with two columns - some complex `data` and a boolean `flag`, is there a way in PostgreSQL to:

- If the result has exactly 1 row, and a `flag` column is `true`, the result should be empty.
- In any other case, the result should be returned whole, regardless of the `flag` value.

```sql
-- This needs filtering:
SELECT data, flag FROM (...) src;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strange requirement, but window functions can do it:

```
SELECT data, flag
FROM (SELECT data, flag,
             count(*) OVER () AS c
      FROM (SELECT ...) AS src
     ) AS q
WHERE NOT flag OR c <> 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Seems like this is a fairly in-expensive check.  Map tile generation with PostGIS using several ST_AsMVT produce one row (data blob) per map layer (water, roads, houses, POIs, ...).  If the tile is in the ocean, and it has no data other than the ocean itself (first layer), and the water takes up the entire tile (`flag`), there is no need to store the tile at all.